# How to extract the data between the last two brackets in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, brackets

So for example I have the following column:

1. Hello this is (BR20134)
2. Paris, France (BR10293)
3. (BR62543) Spice girls (BR6729)

I need to have following column

1. BR20134
2. BR10293
3. BR6729

I am using this query to extract what's between columns:

```
select substring(Column FROM '\((BR.+)\)')
FROM Table
```

but obviously it only works if there is one pair of brackets in a field and not two.

I am using Postgresql btw.

Thanks

Comment: Why not handle this on the ORM level?

Answer (score 2):

This always extracts the last parenthesized expression:

```
substring(textcolumn FROM '\((BR[^)]+)\)[^(]*$')
```